# Is there a quick way to convert between two coordinate systems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, torque, statics

I am solving a few Statics problems that ask to find the resultant moment that a given force produces about a given axis. The problem has two sets of coordinate systems (x, y, z) and (x1, y1, z) where x1, y1 are shifted with a 30 degree angle from x, y (clockwise). There are lots of trigonometric conversions to be made for solving the problem, and it gets complicated to go through every one of them step by step. So, I was wondering if there is a set of transformations that can give me directly the coordinates in x1,y1 by having the coordinates in x, y

Answer (score 4):

If you have a coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ and you want to transform to a new coordinates $(x',y',z)$ via a rotation by an angle $\theta$ about the $z$-axis, then
$$x'=x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)$$
$$y'=-x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)$$

which can also be put in matrix form

$$ \begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

In your case, you'd have $\theta=-\pi/6$.  It doesn't get much simpler than that.